# What is the best way to call an SLO endpoint when Devise times out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on

I am using Devise's `Timeoutable` module. For users logged in with SSO, I want to hit the SLO endpoint on the Identity Provider when their session times out.

I'm trying to figure out the best place to insert this logic.

`Timeoutable`'s logic resides mainly in its `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` hook and it seems to me that this is the right place to put my SLO callout. But this solution would (I think) require me to replace `Timeoutable` with my own customised version which seems a bit clumsy.

I've also considered putting the logic in a custom failure app, something like

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = Class.new(Devise::FailureApp) do
      def redirect
        if warden_message == :timeout && its_an_sso_session
          redirect_to slo_path
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

For this to work, I'd need to store the fact that it's an SSO session somewhere that the Failure App can see, such as a cookie (currently I'm storing it in the Rails session itself, which has been destroyed by the time we reach the Failure App).

Any thoughts on the best way to do this? Is there perhaps some other hook somewhere I can use?